# Restful resteasy - Cliente (ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, web-service, restful

Estou tentando acessar um *WebService*

### Código:

```
public void testeWSRestful() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/teste");
    Response response = target.request().get();
}
```

E está acontecendo o seguinte

### Erro:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.(Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory;)V: org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.(Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory;)V

### Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está faltando, ou onde está o erro?

Comment: Fiz um teste local usando estas mesmas dependência e funcionou em uma aplicação java. Pela mensagem esta executando uma aplicação no *JBoss*, certo? Qual a versão do *container*? Se é mesmo no *JBoss* / *Wildfly*, tente alterar o escopo das dependências para `provided`.

Comment: Estou usando aqui o _JBoss7_ e _JEE7_ . Alterar para `provided` na minha `contoller`? Obrigado

Comment: Alterar para `provided` na aplicação que você tem este cliente REST(`testeWSRestful`) e fazer o *deploy* novamente.